# Rest resquest resourse is not available

Tags: java, rest

Hitting Url with http-

```
localhost:8080/A_Star_Algorithm/rest/GridResource/default
```

getting 404 error:

> The requested resource is not available.

I am not able to solve the problem. Tried everything. Read all existing blogs. Any help appreciated.

[image: Attached screen shot of Code, web.xml and libs]

Answer (score 0):

In `<init-param>`  you need to register with your application package

```
<param-value>your-application-package</param-value>
```

Your URL should be  `localhost:8080/<WAR-FILE-NAME>/rest/GridResource/default`